# How to move a UITableViewCell within a UITableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I really wonder why this question hasn't popped up here so far.
I have a UITableView with custom UITableViewCells in it. The Table itself is editable and contains deletable cells as well as insertable ones.

if a cell is being deleted i want it to become insertable again AND it to move to the bottom of the table.

any clues on how to change a UITableViewCells position within a UITableView?

thx in advance

sam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change the position of cells you need to look to your implementation of [UITableViewDataSource](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UITableViewDataSource) Protocol and specifically the method:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```